# Add a href to jquery grid column (jquery and struts2)

Tags: jquery, struts2

How can I add a href to a jquery grid column or redirect to a new page when a row is clicked ?
I'm using the struts2 jquery plugin.

Here is my grid column -

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="eventName" index="eventName" title="Company" sortable="true" href="/thankyou.jsp" targets="eventSearchResultsDiv">
</sjg:gridColumn>
```

When the grid is displayed I am not able to click the event name.

Thanks

Comment: If you're familiar with jquery why not use it directly? Then you can ask jquery/javascript questions and you'll have a very large audience and you can ask struts2 specific questions separately and reach the appropriate audience. I use both s2 and jquery but not with the jquery plugin, I'm curious what advantages it provides.

Comment: I know a little about jquery. Advantages as I see it are that there is not javascript code on my jsp page, just the jquery plugin tags. I take your point though, using jquery directly is a better way of doing things. I'm just trying to get my app relatively quickly, so the plugin seemed like a good choice. Thanks for you comment though

Comment: I think your app will be up quicker without it, just put the proper include in the header with the script tag and in the value parameter use the s:url tag "s:url value='/script/jquery-1.4.4.js'" with script tags you should have all your JS external to the page just as your CSS probably is. I think this is the faster way, there will be copy and paste into each JSP but once you have it working then you can work on templates to remove the cut and paste (tiles is my favorite, another S2 plugin).

Comment: Ok, how can I answer this question for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using a href in your grid column you should use a formatter.

see related [wiki page at google code](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/FormatGrid).